# Apache Skywalking - Instrumentation of Application Classes

Tags: java, instrumentation, apm, skywalking

I have recently started exploring skywalking as APM tool.

I am interested in looking at the time spent by methods/functions at application layer. Basically a instrumentation sort of thing for the JAVA application. With Skywalking I just get 3 spans(methods) that have one root function and two DB execute functions. I tried adding the property

```
'plugin.jdkthreading.threading_class_prefixes=${THREADING_CLASS_PREFIX=my.package}'
```

But this dint work. I could still see only 3 spans in the dashboard for the API being hit. Under Profile feature I can get the thread stack. But i am only interested with Hotspot methods. Am i missing something in configuration?

I want classes starting with particular pattern to be instrumented and captured in trace. How can I achieve this? Or is there any other open source APM tool I can start with?

Answer (score 1):

When using `plugin.jdkthreading.threading_class_prefixes=${THREADING_CLASS_PREFIX:my.package}`, please make sure to move the `jdk-threading-plugin` under `optional-plugins` folder into `plugins` folder because `jdk-threading-plugin` is disabled by default and you need to move it to `plugins` to enable it.

In terms of hotspot methods, you have 2 ways:

- Use XML-based configuration to instrument your methods, https://github.com/apache/skywalking/blob/2dcf27b79940d60a2e2f19cc7ba9eb9730a463a6/docs/en/setup/service-agent/java-agent/Customize-enhance-trace.md#L1
- Programmatically instrument your methods by using `api-toolkit-trace` [SDK](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.skywalking/apm-toolkit-trace), like this:

```java
@Trace
@Tag(key = "tag1", value = "arg[0]")
@Tag(key = "tag2", value = "arg[1]")
@Tag(key = "username", value = "returnedObj.username")
@Tag(key = "age", value = "returnedObj.age")
public User methodYouWantToTrace(String param1, String param2) {
    // ActiveSpan.setOperationName("Customize your own operation name, if this is an entry span, this would be an endpoint name");
    // ...
}
```